# Why does my Azure Cosmos DB SQL API Container Refuse Multiple Items With Same Partition Key Value?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) I've created a container whose "partition key" is set to `/part_key` and I am now trying to create and edit data in Data Explorer.

I created an item that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "test_id",
    "value": "val000",
    "magicNumber": 32,
    "part_key": "asdf"
}
```

I am now trying to create an item that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "frank",
    "value": "val001",
    "magicNumber": 33,
    "part_key": "asdf"
}
```

Based on the documentation I believe that each item within a partition key needs a distinct `id`, which to me implies that multiple items can in fact share a partition key, which makes a lot of sense.

However, I get an error when I try to save this second item:

```
{"code":409,"body":{"code":"Conflict","message":"Entity with the specified id already exists in the system...
```

I see that if I change the value of `part_key` to something else (say `asdf2`), then I can save this new item.

Either my expectations about this functionality are wrong, or else I'm doing this wrong somehow. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, It could happen if you are trying to instead a new document with id equal to id of the existing document. This is not allowed, so operation fails.

Before you insert the modified copy, you need to assign a new id to it. I tested the scenario and it looks fine. May be try to create a new document and check

Comment: Thanks. I ended up deleting the container and creating a new one and now it works... I'm chalking this up to being a total newb :S

Comment: glad it helped, but i doubt you have to create the container again which is not necessary. Mark if this helped

Comment: @Sajeetharan - there's really nothing to "mark" - the issue was transient (maybe based on data previously inserted? who knows - we didn't get a glimpse of existing data and exact order of operations). And you provided a general comment, not a definitive answer. Great that the OP resolved their issue but... really nothing to upvote or accept here.

Comment: I've thought about it and the actual question was "what is wrong here" and this answer essentially answers "nothing" and confirms my thoughts, and this did motivate me to scrap what I had and try again, also making it helpful. Therefore I believe this does deserve to be the answer, to an admittedly low quality question.